# Add complete 6 borders for 3D figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I use surf to plot 3D surface, and I try to add borders using "box on", but it can only show 3 borders. see

[image]

However, What I really want is to add all 6 borders for the cube, like this

[image].

Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the axes `BoxStyle` to `'full'`, with the `Box` on. For example:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid( 0:0.1:6, 0:0.1:6 );
surf( x, y, cos(x)+sin(y), 'LineStyle', 'none' );
set( gca, 'Box', 'on', 'BoxStyle', 'full' );
```

[image: plot]